# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') at get xyzArray [as xyzArray] Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-promise, formarray

I'm trying to implement FormArray into my project to generate dynamic FormControls.But I'm stuck at this error which I'm not able to understand.Whenever I create a **getter** method to get my array from FormGroup this error pops up.I'm going to explain the error with all the details....

**Error in Console**

[image]

**When I click at the line pointed with RED ARROW IN ABOVE IMAGE it takes me to this following line of code and points at  `let data = await lastValueFrom(res);`**

```
 public async getScheduleData(): Promise<SchemaSchedule> {
let res = this.http.get<SchemaSchedule>(`${this.host}/api/demo-schedule`);
let data = await lastValueFrom(res);
return data;
```

}

**When I click at the line pointed with BLUE ARROW IN ABOVE IMAGE it takes me to this following line of code and points at `dayForm.get`**

```
 get mondayArray(): FormArray {
        return this.dayForm.get('mondayArray') as FormArray;
      }
```

**Detailed Code Related to Above Error in TS file**

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.scheduleResult = await this.service.getScheduleData();
    this.setDay(
      this.scheduleResult.monday![0]
    );

  }
  async setDay(d1: Duration) {
    this.dayForm = new FormGroup({
      mondayArray: new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
          startTime: new FormControl(d1.startTime),
          endTime: new FormControl(d1.endTime),
        }),

      ]),
    });
  }
  get mondayArray(): FormArray {
    return this.dayForm.get('mondayArray') as FormArray;
  }
```

**When I click at the line pointed with YELLOW ARROW IN ABOVE IMAGE it takes me to this following line of code and points at `index as i`**

```
<div
        class="loop_class"
        *ngFor="
         let item of mondayArray.controls;
         index as i
          "
          >
```

**Detailed Code Related to Above Error in html file**

```
<div class="formArray" formArrayName="mondayArray">
                          <div
                            class="loop_class"
                            *ngFor="
                              let item of mondayArray.controls;
                              index as i
                            "
                          >
                            <div class="dynamic_Forms" [formGroupName]="i">
                              <div class="from">
                                <select
                                  name="from"
                                  id="a"
                                  class="text-sm rounded-lg focus:border-primary border border-[#BCBCBC] py-[10px] px-4 focus:outline-none"
                                  formControlName="startTime"
                                  [ngClass]="monState ? '' : 'hidden'"
                                >
                                  <option
                                    [value]="timing.value"
                                    *ngFor="let timing of timingStart"
                                    selected="{{ timing.selected }}"
                                  >
                                    {{ timing.time }}
                                  </option>
                                </select>
                              </div>
                              <div class="divider">
                                <img src="/assets/icons/add.svg" alt="" />
                              </div>
                              <div class="to">
                                <select
                                  name="to"
                                  class="text-sm rounded-lg focus:border-primary border border-[#BCBCBC] py-[10px] px-4 focus:outline-none"
                                  formControlName="endTime"
                                >
                                  <option
                                    [value]="timing.value"
                                    *ngFor="let timing of timingEnd"
                                    selected="{{ timing.selected }}"
                                  >
                                    {{ timing.time }}
                                  </option>
                                </select>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As `dayForm` is only instantiated after the response from an asynchronous http call (`this.http.get<SchemaSchedule>('${this.host}/api/demo-schedule')` which triggers `setDay()`), this means that from the component's initalisation until the GET call completes, `dayForm` **may be undefined**. It therefore helpful to think of `dayForm`'s actual type as `FormGroup | undefined`

This then leads us to understand that if the getter is trying to access the form control `'mondayArray'` but `dayForm` is undefined, an error will be thrown as the `'mondayArray'` key is missing.

There are a couple of ways we could protect for this, both are valid depending on the use case

1. Modify the `mondayArray` getter to correctly reflect that `mondayArray` will either be a FormArray or undefined. This will mean that you will have to null check `mondayArray` whenever you want to access any information on it (as it could be undefined)

```
get mondayArray(): FormArray | undefined {
  if (!this.dayForm) return undefined;
  return this.dayForm.get('mondayArray') as FormArray
}
```

2. Force the getter to always return an array to satisfy typing `mondayArray` as `FormArray`. This means during initialisation, any code which needs to access `mondayArray` will be fed an empty array (`[]`) instead.

```
get mondayArray(): FormArray {
  return (this.dayForm?.get('mondayArray') || []) as FormArray;
}
```

If there are still errors after making one of these changes, you could try simplifying by using observables instead of `async/await`

`service.ts`

```
public getScheduleData$(): Observable<SchemaSchedule> {
  return this.http.get<SchemaSchedule>(`${this.host}/api/demo-schedule`);
}
```

`component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getScheduleData$()
    .subscribe(
      scheduleData => {
       this.setDay(this.scheduleData.monday[0]);
      }
    )
}

setDay(d1: Duration) {
  this.dayForm =
    new FormGroup({
      mondayArray: new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
          startTime: new FormControl(d1.startTime),
          endTime: new FormControl(d1.endTime),
        }),
      ]),
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of the above solutions worked for me. I tried all of them one by one. With the first solution it throws two more `undefined errors` at `this.mondayArray.push` and `let item of mondayArray.controls` and when I put `! or ?`  at `this.mondayArray!.push` and  `mondayArray!.controls`, It throws an error ` can not read` for  both `push` and `controls`... and also the same `get` error as well. And when I use `Observable` it throws `can not read get` erros pointing at `.subscribe`...

Comment: Here is a stackblitz demonstrating the concept https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6rltd5?file=src/app/schedule/schedule.component.ts. Nothing majorly different except I have simplified the template to demonstrate and replaced the `http.get()` call with an observable with a delay of 1000ms. I also `.push()` another item into `mondayArray` after another delay of 1000ms. At no point does the getter throw an error, despite `dayForm` being undefined for some of the process. Have a look and let me know if you have further questions

Comment: I really appreciate your work. But first thing is I don't have a stream of data coming from backend, the data is just an admin schedule single page, which I just have to update using `PUT`. so I'm not allowed to use `Observable` I have to use `Promise` as I'm emitting or handling single value. And the second thing is I tried to produce code from your stack blitz example. But now the data isn't showing in the first place. Maybe my `dayForm` is undefined somehow and data is not loading because we have an `*ngIf="dayForm"` in html....And I'm seeing the same `can not read get` error...

Comment: Not a problem :) Regarding `Observable` vs `Promise`, it is highly recommended to use `Observable` even for single-value use cases. It may not seem beneficial now, but for more complex streams (e.g. mutliple parallel/sequential http requests), RxJs is far superior to the promise APIs, and these happen a lot in medium-large sized apps. If you are still using promises or async/await and it is not working, is there a chance that your endpoint is not being called at all? Check whether `setDay` is being called, and if not, whether the GET request is fired at all?

Comment: I have two forms. `ScheduleForm` and `dayForm` data is coming in `ScheduleForm` but it's giving error in `dayForm` with same GET request.The GET request is displaying data in `SchduleForm` but not in dayForm. Actually it was also showing data in the `dayForm` with even `Promise` untill I tried implemeting `FormArray`...

Comment: At this stage it might be best to build a stackblitz with minimal reproducible code that demonstrates the issue. That process might help you discover where you have gone wrong, but if not, the rest of us will have some code to play with and give higher quality advice

Comment: Thanks a lot bro for spending soo much time on this issue. But I have solve the issue. And the thing is that the array was empty at the backend. And when I emit some data using swagger than everything started working fine.Again Thank alot.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was that the array was empty at backend. And Angular was receiving nothing in `GET` from api that's why it was giving the error due to empty `get`. When I put some data using swagger at the backend the issue resolved.